# UIDatePicker first value set is not default to read

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, datepicker

I have set the initial date in the datepicker in my application. If I change the value and select it picks it up, however when selecting the value **without** changing the spinner the value it shows is todays date.

I have been trying to use the [UIDatePicker setDate:] method, however I am having problems with it, it wont set. This is my code for 'selecting' the date (action assigned to a button):

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
    fvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    datePicked = [datePicker date];

    self.firstViewData = fvc;

    fvc.passedData = datePicked;

    // if isPickerType = 1 then it is date and time
    // if isPickerType = 2 then it is just date
    fvc.datePicker = isPickerType;

    [self presentViewController:fvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to set the date?

Comment: I want to set the initial date (to a variable to prevent the problem happening) in the `viewDidLoad` method

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];
```

You create a new controller, so it has a new date picker. So, the date it had is the default date.

You should be using the date picker in an existing view controller, not creating a new one if this is the point at which you're trying to get the user chosen date.

If this is really where you're creating the controller then you could set the date you want where you currently try to get the date.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, as you say I (thought) I was accessing the viewcontroller which was instantiated when the app launched. I go from the `FirstViewController` to `FilterViewController` (which is the one in question) so when im doing `*fvc` I am creating a brand new view controller? This would actually explain my memory problem.. how can I reference the **original** view controller and not create a new one

Comment: That depends on how / when you created the original view controller. I would expect that controller to handle the picker delegation and the button to finish, so it would be: `[self.datePicker ...`.